# The modifier async can not by applied to the body of a setter

Tags: dart

How can I use `hashIt` function in setter if editor gives this error

> The modifier async can not by applied to the body of a setter

```
  Future<String> hashIt(String password) async {
    return await PasswordHash.hashStorage(password);
  }

  set hashPass(String pass) async { // error here
    final hash = await hashIt(pass);
    _hash = hash;
  }
```

compiller message: `Error: Setters can't use 'async', 'async*', or 'sync*'.`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The *reason* a setter cannot be `async` is that an `async` function returns a future, and a setter does not return anything. That makes it highly dangerous to make a setter `async` because any error in the setter will become an uncaught asynchronous error (which may crash your program). 
Also, being `async` probably means that the operation will take some time, but there is no way for the caller to wait for the operation to complete. That introduces a risk of race conditions. 
So, it's for your own protections.

If you need to do something asynchronous inside the setter anyway, perhaps log something after doing the actual setting, you have a few options.

The simplest is to just call an `async` helper function:

```dart
set foo(Foo foo) { 
  _foo = foo;
  _logSettingFoo(foo);
}
static void _logSettingFoo(Foo foo) async {
  try {
    var logger = await _getLogger();
    await logger.log("set foo", foo);
    logger.release();  // or whatever.
  } catch (e) {
    // report e somehow.
  }
}
```

This makes it very clear that you are calling an async function where nobody's waiting for it to complete.

If you don't want to have a separate helper function, you can inline it:

```dart
set foo(Foo foo) { 
  _foo = foo;
  void _logSettingFoo() async {
    ...
  }
  _logSettingFoo();
}
```

or even

```dart
set foo(Foo foo) { 
  _foo = foo;
  () async {
    ...foo...
  }();
}
```